# Combining multiple statements to create the column name of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The main table named **MAIN** is created as follows:

[image]

I get the number **3, 6, 8, 12, 16, 25** in name of columns from formula bellow:

```
@Y = power(@X, 5) / 10 - 41 * power(@X, 4) / 24 + 133 * power(@X, 3) / 12 - 799 * power(@X, 2) / 24 + 2869 * power(@X, 1) / 60 - 21;
```

(@Y = f(@X), for example, f(1)=3, f(2)=6). I want to put the fifth row of the column [3STU] into the @NN variable. I mean

```
SELECT @NN=[3STU] from MAIN where ROW = 5
```

But I have to take the number in the column names of the table from the formula (@Y) and then refer to the desired column, and I can't use [3STU] or [6STU] directly. Is it possible to merge @Y and 'STU' and put it in @NN variable? Something like

```
@NN = '[' + @Y + 'STU' + ']'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results - its not clear to me at least what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DaleK, I edit the question, maybe my question is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the function this way:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetColName
(
    @value int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r int

    select @r = power(@value, 5) / 10 - 41 * power(@value, 4) / 24 + 133 * power(@value, 3) / 12 - 799 * power(@value, 2) / 24 + 2869 * power(@value, 1) / 60 - 21

    RETURN @r
END
```

You can then use it to build your query as string, and execute it:

```
declare @X int = 1
declare @row int = 5
declare @colname varchar(max) = cast(dbo.GetColName(@X) as varchar(max)) + 'STU' -- brakets not needed in your case
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select ' + @colname + ' from MAIN where ROW = ' + cast(@row as varchar(max))

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Suppose the MAIN table has just 1 row and I want to use [xSTU] value to assigning it to another variable in my function. For example, m1 = [3STU] (3=GetColName(1)) or m3=[25STU] (25=GetColName(6)). How can I do that?